# Javascript Scroll Handler not firing

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

All I'm trying to do is to call a function when a `DIV` is scrolled.For simplicity sake Im not specifying anything else. Also I am only looking at DOM compliant browsers like Chrome, Safari (not IE).

MY problem is that the scroll handler never gets called. If I replace the `scroll` to `click` , it works when I click. Somehow the scroll is not working.

Please note: I cannot use jQuery :(

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">--long content--</div>
```

**JS:**

```
   function myFunc() {
        console.log('in myFunc');
    }
    var objTable = document.getElementById("test");

    objTable.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
        myFunc();
    }, false);
```

**FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/yymg5/7/

Comment: for people who still get trouble - check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31459066/8757883

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is because the window is scrolling not the div. Try changing your element listener to the parent of the div (in this case the window) like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yymg5/3/).

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    myFunc();
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right. I added an overflow attribute to my DIV and added some content.Now it works even on the DIV object. Have updated the fiddle.

Comment: The anonymous function is unnecessary. You can just pass myFunc as a first order function:

window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunc, false);

Answer (score 27):

i had the similar issue in my case. This code is correct, already answered by [Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15276103/1439321)

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function () {
    myFunc(); 
}, false);
```

**but it wasn't working because window scroll event wasn't firing, since the body was scrolling instead of documentElement.**

I just removed `height: 100%;` style from my body tag and then scroll event started firing.

Comment: @ElliotSchep i was focusing on `height: 100%` property of body.

Comment: Okay. Maybe a comment would have been better though?

Comment: Had the same issue, and the css height: 100%; was the problem. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: You legend. I had this same issue in my Nexjtjs app! Removed height: 100% in the __next div and it then worked. This was trolling me for a while. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

If the [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event) event is not firing despite best efforts then you could instead try [wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event) event:

```js
document.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {console.log('i scrolled')});
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I have a `height: 100%` in my body. Since I just wanted to apply the scroll event in a special div only.

Then, this fixed the issue:

```
document.querySelector('#myDiv').addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    console.log('scroll event fired!')
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by removing `height: 100%;` form `html` and `body` CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2):

It happened because your div has `height: 100%` or `height: 100vh`.
In that case, the scroll event will disable automatically if you gave height:

Remove that div height, Remove any height on its parent, child. Basically, that particular div should scroll not its parent or child.

then this should work.

```
const AppWrapper = document.getElementById('app-content');
AppWrapper.addEventListener('scroll', toggleVisibility);


toggleVisibility = () => {
   console.log('Do your thg');
};
```