# Why doesn't window.addEventListener('scroll', this.someScrollHandler, false) work on IE 10?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, dom-events

I'm currently building a React app with a scroll handler for loading more data in an infinite scroll component. I'm using `window.addEventListener('scroll', this.someScrollHandler, false);` (with throttling), which works on every browser except for IE — no event is handled.

In fact, testing in the IE console, the below code, then scrolling, results in no logging:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { console.log('testing') }, false);
```

What's going on with scroll events and IE?

Comment: your code works for me in IE11

Answer (score 32):

My problem was that I had the body height 100%, that disabled the scroll event.

```
body {
   height: 100%; // <-- will disable window.addEventListener('scroll')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this information, my issue was the same!

Comment: If anyone has a body with 100% height try to target any other element than `window` e.g. `_element_whose_height_isnt_100.addEventListener('scroll', function() { console.log('testing') }, false);` This is how I solved this problem.

Answer (score 6):

After a lot of debugging, the problem was in the css. The app is responsive, so we had a base `overflow-x: hidden` style, then switching to `overflow-x: initial` after a breakpoint. Apparently IE doesn't like initial, so it was still picking up on the overflow hidden, thus preventing scroll events from firing. Switching to `overflow-x: visible` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is a cross-browser scroll event listener (it disables scrolling, but it should work if you replace preventDefault by your handler):

```
function disableScroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
    window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
  window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
  document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}
```

You can see there are a lot of different handlers...