# Vuejs event v-on:scroll.passive not working?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm working with VueJs, I have a problem with event v-on:scroll.passive, I'm searching but it's not have many example, so I can't make it's working.

```
<template>
   <div id="app" v-on:scroll.passive="onScroll">
      <content-component :posts="posts"></content-component>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
  import ContentComponent from './components/ContentComponent.vue';
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
      ContentComponent,
    },
    data(){
      return{
        posts : {},
      }
    },
    methods:{
      .......
      onScroll : function () {
        console.log('aaa');
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

When I scroll down or up into website, don't have anything happen, method onScroll not working, where I wrong ? I'm using lastest Vuejs.

Thanks for help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275969/javascript-scroll-handler-not-firing ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add and remove a listener to the *created* and *destroyed* lifecycle methods of the component respectively, like shown below

```js
  created() {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)
  },
  destroyed() {
    document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very little information to help you. 
HOwever, have you added the custom scroll directive?

Please check this example from Vuejs.org site. It contains the simple reaction to user scrolling.
[CodePen example https://codepen.io/sdras/pen/983220ed949ac670dff96bdcaf9d3338](https://codepen.io/sdras/pen/983220ed949ac670dff96bdcaf9d3338)

Below I have pasted the directive they use for scroll.

```
Vue.directive('scroll', {
  inserted: function(el, binding) {
    let f = function(evt) {
      if (binding.value(evt, el)) {
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', f);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener('scroll', f);
  },
});
```

Comment: I have not tried your way, but now I have added the code to the created () function and it works
window.addEventListener ('scroll', this.onScroll);
I will temporarily leave it. Thanks for your help so much.

Comment: the directive will be useful if you want to apply event listener in more than once place, it is firn to just keep it in local component.