# Problem with the event listener for scrolling

Tags: javascript, dom

I wanted to make a back to top button for my website and everything worked fine- after a certain amount of pixels scrolled it appeared and disappeared if below it, however it only works when the scroll wheel of the mouse is used. If you use the sidebar scroll (that thing you use to scroll at right part of the screen, I don't know how it is caleld) it doesn't work Here is my listener --

```
document.documentElement.addEventListener("wheel", function(){checkposition()});
```

When I change the "wheel" type to "scroll" it doesn't work at all. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Scroll Handler not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275969/javascript-scroll-handler-not-firing)

Comment: hey, can you create a demo in jsfiddle n share the link here so we can debug your code?

Comment: Maybe it's due to the event being listened on `document.documentElement`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.